# Why border radius is only working in 1 corner?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a project (I pasted the part affected) and I am trying to round the 4 corners of the image. So far the container is working but the image only has 1 corner rounded (Bottom right).
I was looking for similar questions because there are few, but I was not able to make my code work with those answers.
Any ideas about what the error might be?

Thank you in advance to anyone who takes the time to read and reply!

```css
.cardcontainer {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainimage {
    width: 260px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
<img class="mainimage" src="./image.jpg" alt="Image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It' because you added `padding-top: 20px;` and `padding-left: 20px;` on that image class. Remove these and you will see the border radius on all 4 corners:

```css
.cardcontainer {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainimage {
  width: 260px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
  <img class="mainimage" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT57B75xIfuwkTT0FO1EHI0TK65RcvXIwQ5nNoMePOy9FMxaV5FJ72u6bHLf9N8v9OcARk&usqp=CAU" alt="Image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the info! Now I was able to make ti work!

Comment: I am glad it worked for you. Consider also upvoting and accepting my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The padding remove the border-radius from the image. One solution would to work with margins.

```css
.cardcontainer {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.mainimage {
    width: 260px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
  <img class="mainimage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400/green" alt="Image">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the hint! I was able to make it work!

Comment: @Pedro You welcome :-)